# Blackmagic device and WebRTC are not compatible

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, video-streaming, video-conferencing, blackmagic-design

I can not use an external camera connected via BlackMagic in WebRTC.
I tried it in my source code, web versions of Google Hangout, appear.in (whereby.com), etc in Chrome, Firefox, Safari. Anything worked.

Any idea how I can make it work at least for one browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Unfortunately, most Blackmagic hardware has proprietary APIs and cannot be used as a standard device.  This is by design.  They only want to support software that fully utilizes the capabilities of their hardware.

The only product I know of that they make that isn't proprietary in nature is the "Web Presenter" which is standard UVC, allowing you to use standard OS-provided drivers and capabilities.